# Hidden UITabBarController with 7 tabs

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, xamarin, hidden

In my project I'm working on with Xamarin.iOS (formerly MonoTouch), I ran into a little problem. I have a UITabBarController which contains 7 tabs (so it uses the "More"-tab). The UITabBarController is hidden to the user, and only serves as an easy way to switch between tabs (with the SelectedIndex property). I have arrow buttons on the bottom of the view that function as previous and next tab buttons.

The problem is that if I hit next after the 4th tab, it won't switch to the 5th view, but to the "More" list instead. Is there a way to subclass UITabBarController and override something so this doesn't happen?

Thanks a lot,
DebboR

Comment: If the tab bar is always hidden maybe you should think about don't using it at all. You can maybe put all your controllers in a mutable array and reference them from the App delegate. The most important think you need to carry about is managing lazy loading for controllers that you didn't load yet at the moment of the call.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look into that. It may be a little over-complicated, as I'm using a storyboard, so I could just 'hard-code' the navigation with segues between all 7 views. The only thing that makes me not wanting to do this is that I can't use a common navigation bar if I give all views a controller (so I can push between them).

Comment: If you want to use a navigation controller than you can use the UINAvigationController delegate to detect a new pushed controller and change the navigation bar to your wishes!

Comment: @cescofry There's no need to do that. You can simply alter the this.NavigationItem in the ViewDidAppear method. Thanks anyway

Comment: of course you can, but then you need to replicate the customization code in each of your controllers. Or subclass your controllers form the same one that contains the customization in it. either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a push-pop navigation structure. I have put custom buttons instead of the back buttons which pop to the first view instead of the previous.

Personally, I think the tab solution (if "More" wouldn't be there) would have been much cleaner and logical than this solution, but it works...

Thanks anyway,

DebboR